# How to install Printing in VirtualBox, using Windows XP on a Mac

Tags: windows-xp, mac, virtualbox, printer

how to setup printing in Virtual Box using Windows XP on a Mac. I've also tried using Bonjour but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about printing from inside of a VM; you need to set up printing however it is normally done for the guest OS (e.g. CUPS if Linux is the guest OS).